# I redefine a standard C library function in a dynamic library, but I can't use it

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, solaris, ld

There is a simple example to describe my problem:

I have 3 files, **main**, **level1.so** and **level2.so**. (My OS is solaris11.3, gcc version is 3.4.3)

In **main**, it calls `execute()` from **level1.so**. And the `execute()` calls `run()` from **level2.so**. And the `run()` calls `fcloseall()` which is redefined in **level2.so**.

`fcloseall()` is redefined to do nothing (it will close all opened fds include stdout, stdin and stderr originally).

Now I want print something around `execute()` in main, but only the message before `execute()` is printed.

The codes are shown below:

The **level2.so** is compiled from *level2.c* and *level2depend.c*.

level2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int run()
{
    fcloseall();
    return 0;
}
```

level2depend.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fcloseall() //redefine the std c function fcloseall
{
    printf("in redefined fcloseall\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The **level1.so** is compiled from *level1.c*.

level1.c

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
int execute()
{

        int (*sofunc)(void);
        void * lib_handle = NULL;   
        char *errorInfo;    
        lib_handle = dlopen("./liblevel2.so",RTLD_LAZY);
        if(!lib_handle)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        sofunc = (int(*)(void))dlsym(lib_handle,"run");
        errorInfo = dlerror();
        if (errorInfo != NULL){
            dlclose(lib_handle);
            return 0;
        }
        int ret = sofunc();
        dlclose(lib_handle);
        return 0;
}
```

The **main** is compiled from *main.c*.

main.c

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

        int (*sofunc)(void);
        void * lib_handle = NULL;   
        char *errorInfo;    
        lib_handle = dlopen("./liblevel1.so",RTLD_LAZY);
        if(!lib_handle)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        sofunc = (int(*)(void))dlsym(lib_handle,"execute");
        errorInfo = dlerror();
        if (errorInfo != NULL){
            dlclose(lib_handle);
            return 0;
        }
        printf("before\n");
        int ret = sofunc();
        printf("after\n");
        dlclose(lib_handle);
        return 0;
}
```

The **makefile** is:

```
all:
    gcc level2depend.c -o level2depend.o -c -g -fPIC
    gcc level2.c -o level2.o -c -g -fPIC
    gcc -shared -g level2.o level2depend.o -o liblevel2.so -fPIC
    gcc level1.c -o level1.o -c -g -fPIC
    gcc level1.o -o liblevel1.so -shared -fPIC
    gcc main.c -o main -g -ldl
clean:
    rm level2depend.o level1.o liblevel1.so level2.o liblevel2.so main
```

I execute main and the result is:

```
root@solaris#./main
before
```

If I change the makefile as `gcc main.c -o main -g -ldl -llevel2`, the result is:

```
root@solaris#./main
before
in redefined fcloseall
after
```

And this is what I want.

I want know why this happen. Thanks!

Comment: why not run it through a debugger and step through your code yourself ?

Comment: the level2 code contains: `#include <stdio.h>` which is where `fcloseall()` is prototyped.   Each of your 'sub' files needs a header file.   when linking main.c, the libraries you defined need to be referenced, so they will be looked at first.   Note: it is always a bad idea to write functions with the same name as the system functions.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I have debugged already, I extracted this example from a quite complex project. And thanks @user3629249, your answer gives an inspiration to me. This problem is like a "Global Symbol Interpose": when a symbol need to be added in global symbol table, it will be ignored if there exists a same symbol. I use `ldd` to find **main** reference `libc.so.1`.  What's more, `fcloseall` is defined in `libc.so.1`.  So if I don't use `-llevel2`, **main** will find the `fcloseall` from `lib.so.1`.

Comment: You may need to link level2 with the `-Bsymbolic` flag, but bear in mind that it's probably not a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. I add `-Wl,-Bsymbolic`, and it works!

Comment: It will work but it can be dangerous, just google Bsymbolic, there's a lot of material around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wrap function provided by ld.

```
gcc -Wl,-wrap,fcloseall ....
```

and in your source code,

```
int __wrap_fcloseall(void)
{...}
```

Comment: Thanks @lyyyuna, your method can solve my problem. I add `-Wl,-wrap, fcloseall` to build **liblevel2.so**, and not add `-llevel2` to build **main**, it works as what I want!  But in my build machine(sol10), `ld` can't recognize `-wrap`...